# How to reclaim and include an existing Windows partition into an Ubuntu installation?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have an Acer Aspire netbook which was running Win 7. It has a 500GB disk which was partitioned into C: and D: drives; about 250GB each. I want to ditch Win 7 for this machine and install Ubuntu as the sole OS.

When I ran the Ubuntu boot disk from the USB as a trial it worked fine and I could see drive D: and was even able to open files on it. I decided to go ahead and install Ubuntu on drive C: instead of Windows. I ticked the option to include LVM based on a comment here that suggested it might allow easier manipulation of partitions.

All appeared to go well and, indeed, the machine seems to work fine. BUT the installation can only see a 250GB disk. So I am wondering how to reclaim and make use of the other 250GB.

From my reading of this forum so far, I am guessing that Ubuntu is not going to be able to deal with the other half of the (physical) disk as it was created by Windows. The correct strategy would appear to be: 1. use a Windows USB boot stick to reformat drive D: and 2. boot into Ubuntu and somehow incorporate that unallocated space into the installation

Step 1 seems feasible to me but I may well get stuck with step 2. Before proceeding, however, I'd just like to ask whether I'm on the right track with this approach? Or have I missed something blindingly obvious?

Comment: It s not because *it was created by Windows* but maybe because you had "dynamic disks" set in Windows? Anyway the best strategy would be to backup any personal files then remove all partitions and start the Ubuntu installation with a clean drive. Note that removing partitions can be done easily in a live session using Disks or GParted, **before** starting the actual installation. If you have your backups (or don't need), go ahead and reinstall with that in mind and using the standard "erase and install..." option, so you can use the entire disk.

Comment: LVM can be easier in some circumstances *if you know how to use it*. If not, stick with the Ubuntu defaults.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I know very little about Ubuntu and absolutely nothing about LVM so I'm happy to stick with the defaults. I'd also be happy to start the Ubuntu installation from scratch, but I need to know how to deal with the 'invisible' Windows partition so that it will be included in the new installation. It's this that would seem to be the crux of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Time to 'fess up and answer my own question. I now discover that the disk was actually 320GB not 500 as I'd thought. So I was trying to reclaim 200GB or so that just wasn't there to be reclaimed. I am a complete numpty, but I now know that and can start to set the bar a little higher. Apologies...